# Почему данный код выдает варн Illegal offset type и не работает

Tags: php, mysql

пытаюсь получить данные из бд и в массиве прибавить значение элемента на полученное число из бд. Но выдает ошибку Illegal offset type как только я начинаю прибавлять значение к элементу в массиве. Можете подсказать в чем ошибка? Код ниже.

```
function setIncomeForLastSevenDays($days){
        $link = mysqli_connect(SQL_ADRESS, SQL_USER, SQL_PASSWORD, SQL_BASE);

        if (!$link) {
            echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
            echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
            echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
            exit;
        }
        $arr = array();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `orders`";
        $res = $link->query($query);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($days); $i++){
            $arr[$i] = 0;
        }

        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            if(in_array($r['data'], $days)){
                $i = array_keys($days, $r['data']);
                (int)$arr[$i] = (int)$arr[$i] + (int)$r['income'];
            }
        }


        mysqli_close($link);
        return $arr;
    }
```

Comment: покажите `var_dump($r);`

Comment: var_dump говорит следущее(запускал перед фор):
```
array(10) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(5) "lalal" ["name"]=> string(5) "lalal" [2]=> string(10) "09.11.2020" ["data"]=> string(10) "09.11.2020" [3]=> string(3) "200" ["income"]=> string(3) "200" [4]=> string(1) "1" ["product"]=> string(1) "1" }```
Я виже что сдесь income имеет значение string однако почему? в бдшке он int

Comment: `(int)$arr[$i] = ...` - тут не нужен (int)

Comment: Убрал однако ошибка осталась

Comment: `$i = $i[0];` - добавьте это после `$i = array_keys(...`

Comment: Сделал спасибо  помогло